# What am I seeing in the Serial Monitor output?

Tags: arduino, nodemcu, sinricpro

This is my code for using an HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor for motion detection using the Sinric Pro motion sensor sketch and combining with an Intructables code I found for the ultrasonic sensor. However, when I upload the code to my NodeMCU board, I get this output in Serial Monitor:

```
14:55:28.265 -> 
14:55:36.662 -> 
14:55:36.662 ->  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)
14:55:36.662 -> 
14:55:36.662 -> wdt reset
14:55:36.662 -> load 0x4010f000, len 3424, room 16 
14:55:36.662 -> tail 0
14:55:36.662 -> chksum 0x2e
14:55:36.662 -> load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 8 
14:55:36.662 -> tail 0
14:55:36.662 -> chksum 0x2b
14:55:36.662 -> csum 0x2b
14:55:36.662 -> v00065ae0
14:55:36.662 -> ~ld
14:55:36.727 -> ����n��r��n|�$�$`#��|r�l�o��N�l`��r�d����
```

Code:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG
  #define DEBUG_ESP_PORT Serial
  #define NODEBUG_WEBSOCKETS
  #define NDEBUG
#endif

#include <Arduino.h>
#if defined(ESP8266)
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#elif defined(ESP32) || defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_RP2040)
  #include <WiFi.h>
#endif

#include "src/SinricPro.h"
#include "src/SinricProMotionsensor.h"

#define WIFI_SSID         ""    
#define WIFI_PASS         ""
#define APP_KEY           ""      // Should look like "de0bxxxx-1x3x-4x3x-ax2x-5dabxxxxxxxx"
#define APP_SECRET        ""   // Should look like "5f36xxxx-x3x7-4x3x-xexe-e86724a9xxxx-4c4axxxx-3x3x-x5xe-x9x3-333d65xxxxxx"
#define MOTIONSENSOR_ID   ""    // Should look like "5dc1564130xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#define BAUD_RATE         115200                // Change baudrate to your need

#define trigPin 6                      
#define echoPin 5                       

bool lastMotionState = false;
unsigned long lastChange = 0;

void handleMotionsensor() {
  unsigned long actualMillis = millis();
  if (actualMillis - lastChange < 250) return;          // debounce motionsensor state transitions (same as debouncing a pushbutton)

  int duration, distance;             //Define two intregers duration and distance to be used to save data
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);        //write a digital high to the trigpin to send out the pulse
    delayMicroseconds(500);             //wait half a millisecond
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);         //turn off the trigpin
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);  //measure the time using pulsein when the echo receives a signal set it to high
    distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;     //distance is the duration divided by 2 becasue the signal traveled from the trigpin then back to the echo pin, then devide by 29.1 to convert to centimeters
    bool actualMotionState = false;
    if (distance < 13)                  //if the distance is less than 13 CM
    {        
     Serial.print("Motion detected. ");                          //execute the Light subroutine below
    }
    
    Serial.print(distance);             //Dispaly the distance on the serial monitor 
    Serial.println(" CM");              //in centimeters
    delay(500);

  if (actualMotionState != lastMotionState) {         // if state has changed
    Serial.printf("Motion %s\r\n", actualMotionState?"detected":"not detected");
    lastMotionState = actualMotionState;              // update last known state
    lastChange = actualMillis;                        // update debounce time
    SinricProMotionsensor &myMotionsensor = SinricPro[MOTIONSENSOR_ID]; // get motion sensor device
    bool success = myMotionsensor.sendMotionEvent(actualMotionState);
    if(!success) {
      Serial.printf("Something went wrong...could not send Event to server!\r\n");
    }
  }
}

// setup function for WiFi connection
void setupWiFi() {
  Serial.printf("\r\n[Wifi]: Connecting");

  #if defined(ESP8266)
    WiFi.setSleepMode(WIFI_NONE_SLEEP); 
    WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true);
  #elif defined(ESP32)
    WiFi.setSleep(false); 
    WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true);
  #endif
  
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.printf(".");
  }
  IPAddress localIP = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.printf("connected!\r\n[WiFi]: IP-Address is %d.%d.%d.%d\r\n", localIP[0], localIP[1], localIP[2], localIP[3]);
}

// setup function for SinricPro
void setupSinricPro() {
  // add device to SinricPro
  SinricProMotionsensor& myMotionsensor = SinricPro[MOTIONSENSOR_ID];

  // setup SinricPro
  SinricPro.onConnected([](){ Serial.printf("Connected to SinricPro\r\n"); });
  SinricPro.onDisconnected([](){ Serial.printf("Disconnected from SinricPro\r\n"); });
  SinricPro.begin(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
}

// main setup function
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE); Serial.printf("\r\n\r\n");

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);           //set the trigpin to output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  setupWiFi();
  setupSinricPro();
}

void loop() {
  handleMotionsensor();
  SinricPro.handle();
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a problem with the way I've tried to combine the two codes or if its something else. Can someone help me by either identifying my mistake or by helping me find/create a new code?

Answer (score 0):

> 14:55:36.727 -> ����n��r��n|�$�$`#��|r�l�o��N�l`��r�d����

1. That's likely because your Arduino Serial Monitor speed is set to a different speed than what you have set in the sketch (115200). Try setting your Arduino Serial Monitor speed to 115200

[image]

2. You are trying to use an ultrasonic sensor rather than a motion sensor (PIR/Microwave) to detect motion this can be done but cumbersome. You will need to add additional logic to stop sending repeated motion-detected events. so try using a motion sensor instead of an ultrasonic sensor if you are a beginner. You can find the motion sensor tutorial here: https://help.sinric.pro/pages/tutorials/motion-sensors/HC-SR501-HC-SR505-AM312-HC-SR312

There's an ultrasonic sensor tutorial that might help you to get an idea if you are still going to use an ultrasonic sensor: https://help.sinric.pro/pages/tutorials/custom-device-types/ultrasonic-sensor/HC-SR04. Try coding to detect motion without Sinric Pro and then try integrating it

Comment: My arduino serial monitor was set to 115200 baud, however I will check again. On the other hand, I am trying to use an ultrasonic sensor rather than a PIR(HC-SR501) because the PIR sensor was being affected too much by the surroundings and producing false positive readings. Is there a way to do this using an ultrasonic or is there a way to reduce the range/sensitivity of a PIR sensor? Thanks for the help btw